# Modify JS Object in Pure Way

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, functional-programming, ecmascript-5

I have a function that transforms a JS object. It derives a new property from an existing one, then deletes the original property. Essentially something like this:

```js
/** Derives "capName" property from "name" property, then deletes "name" */
function transform(person) {
  person["capName"] = person["name"].toUpperCase();
  delete person["name"];
  return person;
}

var myPerson = {
  name: "Joe",
  age: 20
};

var newPerson = transform(myPerson);

console.log(myPerson, newPerson);
```

The function returns the desired `newPerson` object, but also modifies the original `myPerson` object. I would rather do this in a pure way, that doesn't modify the original `myPerson` object.

*Note*: I really need to be ES5 compatible, but I'd like to see the ES6 solution as well.

Comment: Why are you creating `capName` only to immediately delete it?

Comment: Also a typo, my bad!!

Comment: btw, the function is not pure ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For ES5 compatibility, you can use `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(person))`. Be aware that methods attached to `person` are lost on the way because they cannot properly be `JSON.stringify`ed.

```js
/** Derives "capName" property from "name" property, then deletes "name" */
function transform(person) {
  var obj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(person));
  obj["capName"] = obj["name"].toUpperCase();
  delete obj["name"];
  return obj;
}

var myPerson = {
  name: "Joe",
  age: 20
};

var newPerson = transform(myPerson);

console.log(myPerson, newPerson);
```

If you want to retain methods, just iterate over the object keys:

```js
/** Derives "capName" property from "name" property, then deletes "name" */
function transform(person) {
  var obj = {};
  for (var key in person) {
    obj[key] = person[key];
  }
  obj["capName"] = obj["name"].toUpperCase();
  delete obj["name"];
  return obj;
}

var myPerson = {
  name: "Joe",
  age: 20
};

var newPerson = transform(myPerson);

console.log(myPerson, newPerson);
```

Be aware that none of the methods presented does a deep clone. For that, I'd recommend you use something like lodash's `_.clone(obj, { deep: true });`

Comment: @JonasWilms True, but the object OP showed has no own methods. Worth mentioning nonetheless.

Comment: @JonasWilms Added that piece of information and added a version iterating over `ownProperties` of `person`.

Comment: Cool! I'm not currently worried about retaining any methods. Both the solutions here are really nice.

Answer (score 2):

just use `Object.assign` which will create a new object with new reference

```js
function transform(person) {
  var obj = Object.assign({}, person);
  obj["capName"] = obj["name"].toUpperCase();
  delete obj["name"];
  return obj;
}
        
var myPerson = {
  name: "Joe",
  age: 20
};

var newPerson = transform(myPerson);

console.log('newPerson:', newPerson);
console.log('myPerson:', myPerson);
```

Comment: `Object.assign` is also ES2015.

Comment: They explicitly asked ES5.

Comment: @connexo yeah I mixed it with ES2015, but anyway `but I'd like to see the ES6 solution as well.`,  this is not wrong too

Answer (score 2):

Quite easy with destructuring:

```
 const transform = ({ name, ...rest }) => ({ capName: name.toUpperCase(), ...rest });
```

> I really need to be ES5 compatible

Use [BabelJS](http://babeljs.io), it makes your life so much eaiser.

Comment: I can get this to transpile very nicely. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could generate a new object without the unwanted and a new property.

```js
function transform(person) {
    return Object
        .keys(person)
        .reduce(function (r, k) {
            if (k === 'name') {
                r.capName = person.name.toUpperCase();
            } else {
                r[k] = person[k];
            }
            return r;
        }, {});
}

var myPerson = { name: "Joe", age: 20 },
    newPerson = transform(myPerson);

console.log(myPerson);
console.log(newPerson);
```